# Entity Framework not retrieving values when used in WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this action method in MVC which retrieves data from table using a `DbContext`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        TwitterContext context = new TwitterContext();
        List<TwitterUser> Users = context.User.ToList();

        return View(Users);
}
```

It retrieves the values as expected:

[image]

But when I use the same code as a service, it retrieves nothing:

[image]

I am calling the service method from the client like this

```
public class TwitterController : Controller
{
    // GET: Twitter
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TwitterServiceReference.TwitterContractClient client = new TwitterServiceReference.TwitterContractClient("BasicHttpBinding_ITwitterContract");
        List<TwitterServiceReference.TwitterUser> user = client.User().ToList();

        return View(user);
    }
}
```

I am using the same connection strings in both cases

```
 <add name="TwitterContext" 
      connectionString="Integrated Security=true;initial Catalog=TwitterDatabase;server=MYNAME-PC\SQLEXPRESS" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I have all the data filled in the table:

[image]

Why is the data empty? How to solve this?

**UPDATE:**
After checking the SQL Server i see that a database is generated with the name
"TwitterService.TwitterContext , the database is autogenerated when i run the app, and the autogenerated tables data is empty, that is why i am getting empty data returned.

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with service. In one application the context is looking for data in the right place, in the other it is looking in the wrong place. Figure that out.

Comment: i Just checked the SQL Server Management studio, i think the code created database named "TwitterService.TwitterContext" don't know how and with the same tables as DbContext class.

Comment: i used 'Database.SetInitializer<TwitterContext>(null);' in Global.asax still the database is autogenerated when i start the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trials i got the success
i just added this code

```
 public class TwitterContext : DbContext
{
    //Added this Code with the connection string
    public TwitterContext() : base(@"Integrated Security=true;server=MYNAME-PC\SQLEXPRESS;database=TwitterDatabase")
{
        //Disable initializer
        Database.SetInitializer<TwitterContext>(null);
    }
    public DbSet<TwitterUser> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TwitterUserData> UserData { get; set; }
}
```

I first tried adding "TwitterContext" as `base("TwitterContext")` which is the name of my connection string and matches with my DbContext class name which did not work, so i directly added the connection string, the data is retrieved now and is preventing from generating new database.

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to copy your `web.config` connection string to that `app.config`.This might be the issue.

Edit:

i mean the project in which your DataContext class resides

Comment: why app.config? WCF does not use app.config

Comment: host uses app.config, i pasted the connection string in app.config and after that host does not start and gives TypeInitializationException, i thing it is enough to mwntion connectionstring in WCF service web.config file

Comment: Does both project using same db context?

Comment: Yep,after checking SQL server studio, there is an other database generated "TwitterService.TwitterContext" ,it is generating databse when i run the application

Comment: i used 'Database.SetInitializer<TwitterContext>(null);' in Global.asax still the database is autogenerated when i start the app

Comment: i think you are running application on different sql servers.if you are using auto generating database .then the time you r running it will check weather existing database is there or not.if data base is not there means it  will create new database and access data from that database,so restore your database to new sql server and run the application this may solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The `TwitterUser` type you are using in MVC is in namespace `Twitter.Models` but the one you are using in WCF is in namespace `TwitterServiceReference`. Therefore, EF will treat them like different things. Your `TwitterContext` is also in different namespaces and as a consequence this is what is happening (from your comment):

> I Just checked the SQL Server Management studio, i think the code created database named "TwitterService.TwitterContext" don't know how and with the same tables as DbContext class

And since it is a brand new database, it has no data and therefore in the WCF service you are not getting any records.

You can have different contexts and use the same database by specifying the same connection string as shown below:

```
public class TwitterContext : DbContext
{
    public MovieDBContext()
        : base("TwitterContext")
    {

    }
}
```

---

**A Better Approach**

Create a separate project and put all your `DbContext` related code in that project. Most people will refer to this as the *Data Access Layer*. Then use that project in both the MVC application and the WCF services. This way you will share the `TwitterUser` and other types in both, and possibly more, applications. You may use [Repository Pattern](http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/repository-pattern-done-right/) to implement this layer.

---

**But what if my MVC application needs additional info?**

There will be cases where `TwitterUser` may not be sufficient for your MVC views and you may need additional properties. In that case, you can create a *Model* specifically for that view (some people call this view model but I stay away from that since that is a term used in MVVM and it is very different). The class can be designed like this:

```
public class TwitterUserModel
{
    public TwitterUserModel(TwitterUser user)
    {
        this.TwitterUser = user;
    }

    public string AnotherPropertyNeededByView {get; set;}

    public TwitterUser TwitterUser { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) or similar mappers to map from `TwitterUser` to `TwitterUserModel`.

Comment: so if i create a separate project for DbContext code, then i have to use that project in both Server side and client side app ?

Comment: You can use it anywhere. Yes.